# Adding an eventListener to a object created by a function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder

I have looked around at a few different threads and can't seem to find anything that works for me.  I am fairly new to ActionScript, so this may be obvious.  For practice, I am trying to make a simple game.  In the game you can chop down trees to add to your 'wood' resource.  Here is the tree class:

```
 package
 {
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Tree extends Sprite
    {

    //Embed the gameObject image
    [Embed(source="../images/tree.png")]
    public var GameObjectImage:Class;
    public var gameObjectImage:DisplayObject = new GameObjectImage();
    public var gameObject:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function Tree()
    {
        gameObject.addChild(gameObjectImage);
        this.addChild(gameObject);
    }
}
 }
```

Then, I create a function in the Main.as call 'createTree'

```
    public function createTree (xPos:int, yPos:int):void
    {
        var treeName:Tree = new Tree();
        treeName.x = xPos;
        treeName.y = yPos;
        treeName.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, chopWood);
        stage.addChild(treeName);
    }
```

And I have a function called 'chopWood' to remove the tree.

```
    public function chopWood(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        wood++;
        stage.removeChild(e.relatedObject);
        updateResources();
    }
```

In the constructor, I add a tree.

```
        createTree(100,100);
```

And it does add the tree at x:100 y:100.  But the Click event doesn't work.  If I manually add the tree (i.e. not through a function) and manually add the even listener, it works.  I figure this is some sort of encapsulation issue, but I am not sure how to resolve it.  Creating trees needs to be done through a function because the play will need to add trees at some point.

How can I get the click event to work on all of the trees that I add to the stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like it should work. Does the chopWood method get called on click? Put a trace at the beginning of `chopWood` to test that.

If `chopWood` is being called, then I can see one strange thing. I am not too sure what `e.relatedObject` is. I would think you would want `e.currentTarget as Tree`. Also you can omit the "stage" in your `stage.removeChild(e.relatedObject);` line. It should just add it to as a child of your Main class.

Comment: Thank you!  I kept assuming chopWood wasn't being called, but it was.  I changed it to 'e.currentTarget as Tree' and it works great!  Sadly, I didn't see 'currentTarget' in Adobe's help and went with 'relatedObject.'

Comment: No worries. `MouseEvent` actually extends `Event`, and `currentTarget` is a property of `Event`. In the AS3 docs make sure you click "Show Inherited Public Properties" at the beginning of the list of properties, to get the full list of properties available.